# opc da and write values to a xml file and read it from a webpage

Tags: xml, client, plc, opc, opc-da

Hi have a OPC Da server which is connected to a softcontroler. both the softcontroller and the OPC da server is created by the program compact control builder(PLC programming software). Now i want to access the variables via a webpage and in order to do this i have planned to write the current values of the OPC Da server to Xml file and then have a webpage that read this one. However i dont now how to write and keep updating the Xml file when the values changes in the OPC Da server. Anyone that has done anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. I used a third-party library called SLIK-DA to create an OPC client and read the OPC DA information. There are several commercially available ones, this is just the one I happened to use. As far as updating the XML file, there would be many ways to do it. The simplest would be to poll all the values at a fixed time interval with a timer or thread.